# Why is the array_unique version faster

Tags: php, benchmarking

I was discussing with a colleague which was faster and we did a small benchmark:

```
function uniqueByKey(){
    $strings = [];
    $stopwatch->start('test');

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {
        $strings[RandomStringUtil::generate()] = 1;
    }

    $outcome = $stopwatch->stop('test');
    die($outcome->getDuration()/1000);

    self::assertSame(25, count($strings));
}
```

And

```
function uniqueByFunction(){
    $strings = [];
    $stopwatch->start('test');

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {
        $strings[] = RandomStringUtil::generate();
    }
    $strings = array_unique($strings);

    $outcome = $stopwatch->stop('test');
    die($outcome->getDuration()/1000);

    self::assertSame(25, count($strings));
}
```

I was expecting method `uniqueByKey` to be faster, as accessing arrays by key is very fast, and the array unique now had 1.000.000 values to check for uniqueness.

However, `uniqueByKey` took (on average of a few runs) a consistent ~12.5sec, the `uniqueByFunction` only about ~11.8sec.

In our use case we only loop 25x, so the difference isnt worth noting, however we are curious why the latter is faster than the first. Can anyone explain?

<sub>If it matters, tested on a MacbookPro 2020 edition)</sub>

Comment: according to me : doing `RandomStringUtil::generate()` and then explicitly making it array index and then doing assignment will definitely take more time than native assignment  of `$strings[] = RandomStringUtil::generate();`

Answer (score 2):

I try this:

```
$base = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $base[] = md5($i);
}

$start = microtime(true);
$array1 = [];
foreach ($base as $random) {
    $array1[$random] = 1;
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start . PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
$array2 = [];
foreach ($base as $random) {
    $array2[] = $random;
}
$array2 = array_unique($array2);
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start . PHP_EOL;
```

and I got the same result as you, but if I try this:

```
$base = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $base[] = md5($i);
    $base[] = md5($i);
    $base[] = md5($i);
}

$start = microtime(true);
$array1 = [];
foreach ($base as $random) {
    $array1[$random] = 1;
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start . PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
$array2 = [];
foreach ($base as $random) {
    $array2[] = $random;
}
$array2 = array_unique($array2);
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start . PHP_EOL;
```

I got the opposite result. `array_unique` is not always faster

Comment: I like that something has influence on it, but now I have an additional question: Why does *that* matter?

Comment: @Martijn It seems `array_unique` is using Quick sort, its average complexity is O(nlog2n), single array key access is O(n) and it repeats n times, so the real complexity might be O(n2), slower than Quick sort. In my second example, Quick sort meets [the 'worst' case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Worst-case_analysis)